How to close a python program anytime a key is pressed?
I was trying to make a bot that farms Microsoft points and I wanted the macro to stop anytime I pressed the "Esc" key, I was using the keyboard module to check if the "Esc" key was being pressed and close the program if the key was being pressed, but I was also using the time.sleep() function to wait some time for the web page to load so that I can get points, but I found that if I press the "Esc" key while the program is on the time.sleep() part then the program doesn't end. Please help.
import webbrowser,time,random,pyautogui,requests,keyboard
def close():
    with pyautogui.hold("Ctrl"):
            pyautogui.press("w")

def generate():
    with open("wow","r",encoding="utf-8") as f:
        p = eval(f.read())
        search = random.choice(p)+"+"+random.choice(p)+"+"+random.choice(p)
    with open("wow1","r",encoding="utf-8") as f:
        p = eval(f.read())
        c = random.choice(p)
        url = c.replace(" ",search)
    return url
def links():
    while ():
        url = generate()
        webbrowser.open(url)
        webbrowser.open("https://rewards.bing.com/pointsbreakdown")
        requests.get("https://rewards.bing.com/pointsbreakdown")
        ''' try:
                no = requests.get(url=points)
        except Exception as err:
            if type(err) == requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
                print("Internet connection issues, Retrying ...")
            else:
                print(err)
            continue
        print(no)'''
        time.sleep(3)
        for i in range(2):
            close()
webbrowser.open("example.com")
time.sleep(0.2)     
links()
close()


I was hoping to see if anyone could tell me if there were any alternative modules or some alternative method of doing this.

Because that's not cheating AT ALL, right?   You can always press Ctrl-C to exit.

You can possibilly use a while loop for this..!
In the list lines of your file..
webbrowser.open("example.com")

startT = time.time()
while(time.time()-startT < 0.02):
    pass
     
links()
close()

